# How do you make Handles clauses dynamic?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to use a `Handles` clause with a variable whose value can be changed at run time.

The following example code works fine:

```
Private Sub thepic1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
        System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles picbox1.mouseup
```

What I want to do is the following:

```
Dim ABC as string = "picbox1.mouseup"

Private Sub thepic1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
        System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ABC
```

I am very much a novice and would appreciate any help.  Thanks.

Comment: You don't want this: `Dim ABC as string = "picbox1.mouseup"`. You probably want [AddHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement). It allows you to *attach* a delegate to an event of a control you specify at run-time. E.g., `AddHandler thepic1.MouseUp, AddressOf MyMouseUpHandler`. `MyMouseUpHandler` is a void (`Sub`) method that matches the event delegate signature: `ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs`.

Comment: Remember to call [RemoveHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/removehandler-statement) to remove the subscription when you don't need the event handler anymore (or the Form closes).

Comment: @Jimi Would you like to take your comments and put them in an answer?  You may have to explain it a little bit further, but your comments sound like a good answer.

Comment: @Panzercrisis Maybe. If that's what the OP is actually after. There's a chance that the reason why the OP is trying to do this, causes it all to land on a completely different page of the manual.